# Determinants, traces and isomporphism of graphs

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

**Question**
Prove that if A,B are adjacency matrices of two graphs, and their traces or determinants are not equal then the graphs are not isomorphic.

**Thoughts**
I know that 2 graph are isomorphic iff $P^tAP=B$ (some kind of similarity, normal?)
Can I grasp that if the trace/det are not equal then this equality doesn't hold because equal dets/trs are sufficient conditions for similarity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix $P$ that you use here is in fact a permutation matrix, so $P^t=P^{-1}$ (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix#Properties)), thus you have that the graphs are isomorphic iff $P^{-1}AP=B$, that is, iff the adjacency matrices $A$ and $B$ are similar via a permutation matrix.

Now, it is a basic linear algebra fact that similar matrices have the same characteristic polynomial (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity#Properties)), in particular, similar matrices have the same determinant and the same trace.